# MS Access ODBC with PostgreSQL Table Write Conflict

Tags: vba, postgresql, ms-access

So I have to transfer the back end of an Access Database to Postgres recently. After linking the tables to the forms and updating the VBA coding, I tried to create a new record with the primary key field. I verified that this field was created successfully through the back end, but when I try to insert new data into the fields and upon saving the data Access always give me this error.

*"Write Conflict:this record has been changed by another user since you started editing it. If you save the record, you will overwrite the changes the other user made."*
And I am only given two options: Copy to Clipboard and Drop Changes.

The weirdest part is that if I try to open an existing record and modify the fields, I can save successfully. The write conflict error only pops up on the new records that I added.

I tried do some research online, and I had add time stamps to the table and all tables have PKeys. Can anyone explain the reason behind this? Very much appreciated!

Comment: Can I assume you are using a Postgres ODBC driver? If the Access tables use AutoNumber fields, do the correspond linked tables reflect them?

Comment: In Access can you open one of the linked tables in Datasheet mode and manually add a new record there?

Comment: @rontornambe: Yes, I am using an ODBC driver and and i used the serial type to reflect auto number fields.

Comment: @GordThompson:Good point. I can enter in the primary key and the auto number can get automatically filled in. But when I try to enter any other fields, it gives me the write conflict again.

Comment: So a workaround would be: Make a query of the odbc-linked Table, without the timestamps columns (created_at, updates_at), you will not have any conflicts anymore.

Answer (score 7):

I know that this question is old, but problem still exists (tested on *MS Access 2013*) and some people might be looking for solution.

According to [PostgreSQL FAQ](https://odbc.postgresql.org/faq.html#6.4) this is caused by slight differences between Access and Postgre in 2 specific cases. While updating a record, access adds some conditions to ensure that record wasn't changed by anybody. If any of them fail database returns that no records were updated, which is interpreted as they were modified in the meantime.

#### Empty strings

Access doesn't know the difference between empty string (`''`) and *NULL* while postgre does. If you leave empty string in a field, Access add `... AND column_name IS NULL"` which fails in database. There's only workaround currently - **make sure that all empty strings are stored as *NULL***.

#### Timestamps

PostgreSQL timestamp has microsecond precision while Access supports only milliseconds. In this case Access rounds the excess, so for example `2016-02-22 12:34:56.788952` is converted to `2016-02-22 12:34:56.789` which later fails on comparison. This can be fixed by lowering precision of the timestamp in database. **Change `timestamp` type to `timestamp(3)` (for millisecond precision) or `timestamp(0)` (for second precision)**.

I hope it helped.

Comment: *"Access doesn't know the difference between empty string ('') and NULL"* - That is not true. In Datasheet view or a Text Box control if we leave the field empty then Access will interpret it as NULL, but if we enter `""` into that control then Access will interpret it as a zero-length string.

Comment: Good point. But as far as I know, if database returns empty string, Access interprets it as NULL and that causes the issue. I might oversimplified this in my answer.

Comment: Lowering timestamp precision fixed my issue. Timestamp was being updated in background by a trigger, rather than being sent by MS Access, so it had higher precision.

Comment: Changing the timestamp precision worked. You've saved my day sir. I thought I was going to have to do without timestamps!

Comment: Thank you so much.  Lowering the precision worked for me too.  Access would continue to warn about write conflicts until this fix.